# php Fatal error: Cannot use object PHPMAILER of type as array

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email, smtp

Estou com problemas para realizar o envio de e-mail.

**Código**

```
<?php
#inclui a classe PHPMAILER
include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"); //pasta em que a classe se encontra
#instancia o objeto
$mail = new PHPMailer();
#enviar via SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
#seu servidor smtp / dominio no meu caso "mail" mas pode mudar verifique o seu!
$mail->Host = " smtp@teste.com.br ";
#habilita smtp autenticado
$mail['smtp_port'] = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
#usuário deste servidor smtp. Aqui esta a solucao
$mail->Username = "smtp@teste.com.br";
$mail->Password = "teste"; // senha
#email utilizado para o envio, pode ser o mesmo de username
$mail->From = "smtp@teste.com.br";
$mail->FromName = " smtp@teste.com.br ";

#Enderecos que devem receber a mensagem
$mail->AddAddress("contato@teste.com.br","Contato");
#$mail->AddAddress("comercial@teste.com.br","Contato");
#wrap seta o tamanhdo do texto por linha
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
#anexando arquivos no email (supondo estar no mesmo diretorio)
// $mail->AddAttachment("arquivo.zip");
// $mail->AddAttachment("foto.jpg");
$mail->IsHTML(true); //enviar em HTML

#recebendo os dados do formulario
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
$nome    = $_POST['nome'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$como = $_POST['como'];
$ddd  = $_POST['ddd'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
#informando a quem devemos responder. o mail inserido no formulario
$mail->AddReplyTo("$email","$nome");
#criando o codigo html para enviar no email, voce pode utilizar qualquer tag html
$msg  = "Contato Site";
$msg .= " Nome: $nome\n";
$msg .= " E-mail: $email\n";
$msg .= " Como nos conheceu?: $como \n";
$msg .= " ddd: $ddd \n";
$msg .= " telefone: $telefone \n";
}

$mail->Subject = "ASSUNTO DO EMAIL";
#adicionando o html no corpo do email
$mail->Body = $msg;
#enviando e retornando o status de envio
$mail->send();
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "houve um erro ao  enviar o email! erro: $mail->ErrorInfo";
#$mail->ErrorInfo informa onde ocorreu o erro, o uso opcional
exit;
}
echo "Mensagem enviada ok";
?>
```

**Erro**

> php Fatal error: Cannot use object PHPMAILER of type as array

Comment: Desconfio que o erro seja aqui `$mail['smtp_port'] = 465`, como sugere a mensagem de erro isso deve ser acessado como um objeto e não um array, logo o correto seria: `$mail->smtp_port = 465`

Comment: se alterar isso não é possível acessar o email SMTP@gmail.com

Comment: aparece esses erros

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/XYZTERSA/public_html/class.smtp.php on line 90

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp@gmail.com.br :465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/XYZTERSAa/public_html/class.smtp.php on line 90

Comment: Sim é possível! http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/XYRSA/public_html/class.smtp.php on line 90

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp@gmail.com.br :465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/TEA/public_html/class.smtp.php on line 90
 houve um erro ao enviar o email! erro: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: Uma dica , lembre-se de adicionar uma contextualização do problema ao adicionar um novo tópico , exemplo :"Estou com problemas para realizar o envio de e-mail." isso irá contribuir tanto para o pessoal compreender o seu problema e ajudar futuramente quem fizer uma pesquisa buscando uma resposta para o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Altere a linha:

`$mail['smtp_port'] = 465;`

por

`$mail->port = 465`

Lembre-se se logar no google e ir até a página: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

E garantir acesso do phpmailer ao email destino